# Unable to make ajax request to remote server from localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax request (with jquery) from my local server to a remote page (which I am the admin) and I get

```
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://ica.local.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

This is how my request looks like:

```
$.ajax({
  url:  myurl,
  type: "POST",
  // This is the important part
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  // This is the important part 
  success: function (response) {
    // handle the response
  },
  error: function (xhr, status) {
    // handle errors
 }
});
```

The application on the remote server is running on nginx server. I tried to change the conf file of nginx to Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * but it still doesnt work.

Comment: If you look at the response headers do you see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header? If not you may have configured your server incorrectly

Comment: There are also other headers required for withCredentials and you also need to make sure OPTIONS requests are handled with CORS headers

Answer (score 2):

It is because both the machines are on different servers. For development purpose you can use chrome extensions already available to fix the purpose.

Just search 'Cross origin issue' on chrome extension page and then include one of extensions

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a sample server file like php and call the remote with curl from php.
Than return the response as json to your is